# Error handling for closed clients in StreamingResponseBody in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was wondering if there is a way to find out if a client has closed the connection of a `StreamingResponseBody` while data is still being written to the outputstream. My Spring Boot controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/zip")
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> zip(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=download.zip");

        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
            try (ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream)) {
                // loop over files
                final ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(path);
                zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = bufferedInputStream.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                    zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
                }
                zipOut.closeEntry();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // error handling
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The application takes some files and puts them in a ZIP file as response. Under normal operation, this application works fine.

If the client aborts the download of the ZIP file, the application continues to put files in the ZIP, but fails eventually with a `ClientAbortException` (after several minutes). Here is a detailed error message:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:776)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:681)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:645)
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:645)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:253)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211)
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.write(ZipOutputStream.java:331)
```

So would it be possible to stop the processing related to this request when the client closes the connection? Otherwise useful resources would be wasted.

Comment: Wish there was an answer to this question as I'm trying to figure out the same thing. Only thing I can think is that you know there is a disconnect when you try to write to the stream and it fails, build event handling around that.